# Zend Framework Cassandra

Tags: zend-framework, cassandra

The cassandra database seems to be very fast,
now I wanted to use it in my project made with Zend Framework.
Is there a adapter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a very new fledgling adapter for Cassandra and the Zend Framework which can be found on GitHub at [Zend_Cassandra](http://github.com/julesbravo/Zend_Cassandra).

Initially it is intended as a thin [Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) layer for Cassandra but progress has been made pretty quickly and the originating team have been working with the Zend Framework Core team on getting it eventually integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/). You can checkout the interfacing for PHP from [here](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/lib/php) using SVN.